# Check if ID exists in DB

Tags: android, sqlite, select

I have a table in my DB, which consists from following fields: id, group_id, uri_id, name, phone.
In my DB manager file I have a function to check if a uri_id exists in group. This is the function:

```
public boolean is_contact_in_group(String uri_id, int group_id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = db_helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor mContactsCursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_GROUP_CONTACTS, null, 
            "group_id="+group_id+"&contact_uri_id="+uri_id, null, null, null, null);


    if(mContactsCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        mContactsCursor.close();
        db.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        mContactsCursor.close();
        db.close();
        return false;
    }

}
```

For now In my activity I just want to log the output:

```
private void add_new_contact(String uri_id, String name, String number)
{
    int group_id = curr_group_id;
    String contact_uri_id = uri_id;
    String contact_name = name;
    String contact_phone = number;
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Is contact exist: "+manager.is_contact_in_group(contact_uri_id, group_id));

}
```

However every time I get `false`, even if there is a record with a certain group_id and uri_id.

Why is it happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Not to nitpick, but I see `c_style_naming_conventions` mixed in with `camelCase` mixed in with `PascalCase` and local variables prefixed with `m(ember)`. I know it's not directly related to the question, but picking consistent formatting can't hurt.

Comment: @sircodesalot Thank you! Will take care of it! :)

Comment: Np. You might also consider the horrors of SQL injection (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx). Generally not a good idea to pass user input straight into a database (image if the user types `delete * from table` instead of a `group_id` or `contact_uri_id`). Should be some way to "parameterize" input so that it gets cleaned of any malicious text.

Comment: @sircodesalot While that's normally good advice, I'm not sure these are user inputs. If an app asked me to manually type in a contact's `uri_id`, I'd probably uninstall it.

Comment: Ah ok. It's always a little unnerving seeing string manipulation in SQL scripts. But, so long as they're aware, that's the important thing

Comment: @sircodesalot Geobits right, these are not user inputs. However I will have some user inputs later in this app and, of course, will have to deal with SQL injection. Again, thank you for your advice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd imagine it's because your `WHERE` clause is wrong.

Change

```
"group_id="+group_id+"&contact_uri_id="+uri_id
```

to

```
"group_id="+group_id+" AND contact_uri_id="+uri_id
```

Comment: Such a rookie mistake... Thanks, it worked! Have to wait a few minutes till I can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

Cursor mContactsCursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_GROUP_CONTACTS, null, 
        "group_id = " + group_id + " & contact_uri_id = " + uri_id, null, null, null, null);

Your Query has not white spaces between sentences.